# Xamarin Android assets folder not updating when building the solution

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Forms app that needs to read data from a json file. I placed the file into the Android assets folder and selected the build action AndroidAssets

[image: Example]

Then I try to load the file in MainActivity with Assets.Open(filename) and I get a FileNotFoundException. I deleted the Android and PCL bin folders and tried to build the project again but got the same result. Then I opened the .apk file in WinRar and when I go to the assets folder, the files that I added to the project are not there.

Does anyone have any idea what's the problem here?

Comment: That's wierd, it should be work. Please note that when you use `Assets.Open()` method, you need use the full  name, for example : `Assets.Open("test.txt")`, you could read this [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/).

Comment: I do use Assets.Open("test.txt") but I still get a file not found error. The strangest part is that even when I set the file's build action to AndroidAsset it doesn't appear in the .apk file after successfully building the app. So I understand why it can't find the file, but what I don't understand is why the file isn't where it's supposed to be after building.

Comment: Would you mind share a basic demo to reproduce this problem ? To make sure we are verifying the exact same thing you are using.

Comment: I tried removing all other files except from test.txt from the Assets folder and rebuilt the project several times and now I get an error message: The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist. I didn't make any changes to the code or any other files other than removing some files in the Assets folder. What's up with that?

Comment: I tried making the demo. At first I wanted to create a new project and recreate the problem but the assets worked fine in the new project. So I removed most of the code from my current project, left the code that causes the error and uploaded it on GitHub here: https://github.com/kzalys/xamarin_error Hope this helps

Comment: Please rename your `finderro-line-no-bg.png` file to `finderro_line_no_bg.png`, you can't use the "-" character in android resource file, then it works fine, I can see the "test.txt" file in the `.apk` file.

Comment: Oh wow, I've wasted so much time with such a silly mistake :D Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with using the "-" character in resource file names. Changed it as suggested by York Shen and it started working as it was supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set the files as embedded resources from the file properties?

If you not, right click on the file -> Properties -> set as Embedded Resources in Build Action

Comment: I set the files as AndroidAssets not as embedded resources as you can see in the picture. Shouldn't that work for an Android app? I tried changing them to embedded resources as you suggested but it didn't make any difference.